# Passing angular 1 controller scope method as callback to captcha library

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a client who is based in china and requires specialised captcha that works there. The captcha I need to use is here https://open.captcha.qq.com/

Basically there are 4 steps to get it working:

1. In the  label of html, add this line:

   ```
   <script src="https://ssl.captcha.qq.com/TCaptcha.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add id and property to any DOM element that we want to activate captcha, such as button, div or span. Sample code as below:

   ```
   <button id="TencentCaptcha"
   data-appid="2090807227"
   data-cbfn="callback"
   >验证</button>
   ```
3. Then create callback function in javascript:

   ```
   function callback(res){
       console.log(res)
       if(res.ret == 0){
          alert(res.ticket)   // ticket
      }
   }
   ```
4. From the callback, make a POST request to the server to validate the ticket

I'm struggling this to incorporate this into my UI which uses Angular 1.5.6.

My controller is:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.oldCallback = function(){
    console.log('in the old callback');
  };

  $scope.newCallback = function(){
    // PASS THIS AS THE CALLBACK TO NEW REGISTER BUTTON
  };
})
```

I have created a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqNZVx?editors=1010).

The only way I can get it remotely working is if I pass in a method in the HTML e.g.

```
  <button type="submit" id="TencentCaptcha"
   data-appid="2090807227"
   data-cbfn="(function(res){alert('res is ' + res)})">
    Register
  </button>
```

After clicking Register, the captcha library presents a popup with a challenge to the user. Once completed, the callback passed to `data-cbfn` is executed. How can I call my controller method from this callback, passing through the result?

Comment: what is your exact question? maybe this can help you: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: have updated question

Comment: Is it safe to assume that your button does not reside in a view that your controller has access to?

Comment: It does, it's in the template for that controller...

Comment: You need to expose the function globally first and then render the button from the template.

Answer (score 1):

I created a global function and was then able to call the correct method in the controller:

```
function callback(){
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("home")).scope();
    scope.register();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add your function to the window from your angular controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

  $window.callback = function callback(res) {
      $scope.register();
  };
});
```

This way you don't have to request the document element which may change scope or id later on.

Also: `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` will actually disable the functionality to retrieve the scope from a document element like you've done.

You should be turning off the debugInfo functionality in production mode for performance and security reasons.